# Name of city replaced by transliteration. Why?

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I've spotted that employers in my city, Moscow, Russia, actually listed as situated in "Moskva". When I asked about that, I was told that Stack Overflow automatically replaced "Moscow" with "Moskva". It a transliteration that is sometimes used, but it is unlikely that someone would search for "Moskva". Why does this happen and why there is no option disambiguate it or offer both variants?

E.g. [https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/151558/react-front-end-full-stack-web-developer-confirmit-ltd-russia?so=i&sec=False&pg=1&offset=0&l=Moskva%2c+Москва%2c+Россия&d=20&u=Km](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/151558/react-front-end-full-stack-web-developer-confirmit-ltd-russia?so=i&sec=False&pg=1&offset=0&l=Moskva%2c+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2c+%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F&d=20&u=Km)

Comment: I've seen reports before that indicate that SO uses a 3rd-party dataset for those names, and some of them are indeed wrong.

Answer (score 13):

We use Google to provide our geo-lookups and provide a region hint based upon the geolocation of the browser posting the job listing. I imagine this listing was posted from Russia so we asked Google for the results for [Moscow](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=False&address=Moscow&region=RU). That returns 'Moskva' as `administrative_area_level_2` which we use for our city fields.

However, it also reports that for all other region hints I pass to it, so I suspect that this is a problem with the data on Google's end.

Why does it work in search? When searching we geocode the location text you provide using the same process and then perform a geo query based upon lat/lon or a bounding box (depending on the specificity of the location) so it doesn't actually make a difference to search. If you search for 'Moscow' you get the same results as if you search for 'Moskva'.

So, this may be a bug, but it looks like bad data on Google's side of things. It also doesn't affect surfacing jobs so I'm gonna mark this as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: administrative_area_level_2  is  not used level of administrative differentiaon in country.  That string must be placeholder. oh, that response is a bit of  screwed up, because they translate Moscow to Local language, Москва, then give you  transliteration to latin1. Search in fact doesn't work for me, sometimes at random it gives single Moskva, but otherwise it  just spews random locations or   Moscow , ID (USA). I guess,  my location affects it? Ironically, I'm right in there

Comment: @Swift are you sometimes connected to a VPN? If you're coming to us with a US IP address and type just Moscow it'll give you the US Moscow, not the real one.

Comment: @Swift The response likely isn't screwed up. They use the language of the client for the names. SO is likely getting [the English response](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=False&address=Moscow&region=RU&language=en), while I get [the German](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=False&address=Moscow&region=RU&language=de) and you [the Russian one](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=False&address=Moscow&region=RU&language=ru) when not specifying a language code. And `administrative_area_level_2` is not translated everywhere :-/

Comment: @DeanWard Based on a bit of research (i.e. looking it up in Wikipedia), it appears that Moscow, Idaho _is_ a real town, not a fake one.  :)  I guess your wording could be improved a tad.

Comment: @Bergi  My system and client language are set to English. It uses my location, I suppose, a problem with Google I as well as many people in Europe ru deal with.  E.g. even f you're even a Dutch-speaking Belgian, google would insist that you speak French, based on the address.